# Extract the last 1 or 2 alphabetic character(s) from a quantity (mg,g,ml,l,cm,mm,m) when preceded by a digit

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I need to be able to populate a cell in a Google Sheets spreadsheet with the measurement units extracted from the end of a string value in another cell. The raw data comes through with every source cell ending with a measurement unit, either preceded with a numeric value or not, as in the example data below...

> **SAMPLE DATA:**
>
> ```
> Colgate Plax Spearmint Alcohol Free Mouthwash 500ml
> Peckish Tangy BBQ Rice Crackers 100g
> Alison's Pantry BBQ Chickpea Snacks kg
> Yoghurt Raisins Miscellaneous Confectionery kg
> Roasted Unsalted Supreme Mixed Nuts kg
> Alison's Pantry Honey & Dijon Snippets kg
> Banana Chips kg
> Sealord Satay Tuna 95g
> Sealord Savoury Onion Tuna 95g
> Coca-Cola No Sugar Soft Drink 2.25l
> Tongariro Natural Spring 15l
> Trident Sweet Chilli Sauce With Ginger 285ml
> Pams Lite Whole Egg Mayonnaise 443ml
> Value Lite Milk 2l
> Morning Harvest Caged Size 7 Eggs 12pk
> ```

> **EXPECTED RESULT:**
>
> ```
> ![New column showing the measurement units][1]
> ```

> **CURRENT METHODOLOGY:**
>
> ```
> =IF(A1<>"",REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^.*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])$|^.*([a-zA-Z])$"),"")
> ```

> **CURRENT RESULT:**
>
> ```
> ![Result being split over two columns][2]
> ```

While I can combine the two values into a third column using the expression **`=IF(B1<>"",B1,IF(C1<>"",C1,""))`**, this becomes messy, convoluted, and adds unnecessary columns. I would prefer to tweak the regular expression to return just a single value, either the one or two character measurement unit. I have no idea how to achieve this, though. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I need at least 10 reputation to post images here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match 1 optional letter, then 1 letter anchored to end:

```
IF(A1<>"",REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "[a-zA-Z]?[a-zA-Z]$"),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also make the pattern a bit more specific matching either a digit of space, and capture one of the units at the end of the string.

```
=IF(A1<>"",REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "[\d ]((?:m?l|[mk]?g|pk|[cm]?m))$"),"")
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ooJUp1/1) for the capture group values.

[image]